# Proper syntax of a specific type of if statement

Tags: windows, if-statement, batch-file, cmd

I am making a text based rpg and I'm struggling with a specific kind of if statement, I'm not inclined to share the exact code as It's got a lot of content in it I have made over the past 5 years that I hope to get a copyright on. (to clarify, I'm regarding the artwork, music and storyline I created myself)

Example of the Code:

```
set choice=00
:top
cls
echo What would you like to do? 
echo 1) gain 10 points
echo 2) do something else
set /p choice=Your Choice:
if %choice%==1 goto :options
if %choice%==2 goto :something-else
if %choice%==00 goto :end

:options
set /a opt1=10
set /a opt2=10
if %opt1%==%opt2%-5 goto :nxt
set /a opt1+=10
goto :top

:nxt
cls
echo You can't do that! 
echo/
echo Press Enter to Continue
pause >nul
goto :top

:something-else
exit

:end
exit
```

The problem is, my process is ignoring this if statement completely. From my perspective opt2-5 should = 5 therefore forbidding the action being attempted, which is to add 10 to opt1, instead it skips the if and adds 10 anyways. This type of equation has worked for me in other areas thus far, I don't understand why it isn't working now. The only difference is the other code had the variables defined completely, ex: opt1=10 opt2=5, if opt2=5 then echo you can't do that.

Comment: batch comparisons are literal. You are attempting to match "<the content of a>" to "<the content of b>-C" You need to first make the calculation `set /a dummy=b-c` and then `if %A%==%dummy% ...`. **ALL** batch variables are strings. You can perform limited mathematics if the strings are strings of integers

Comment: So either way I go about this I'm going to have to take the time to set up each equation. I can either outright say A=E or I can say set /a B-C=E and then A=E, either way it's the same thing. I was trying to save myself an extra step, but I guess I really wasn't, thanks.

Comment: On the copyright comment. Don't get too excited there. Batch code is not compiled. You can try and copyright it all you want, but it is readable in plain text so if I make some minor changes it does now my version of it. If you want to copyright, then use a C# or something similar and compile a proper program.

Comment: Then on the calculations. You can predefine a set of them, if you do it right you can make it much shorter than you think. Give me a few actual examples of use cases so I can see what exactly might be required.

Comment: Gerhard, as far as copyright goes, it's more towards the storyline, music and art implemented into the program as apposed to the code itself, but I understand what you are saying. That being said, my code will be compiled into an executable and be made an actual application when I'm done, albeit that it's environment is still Command Line, it will not be so easy to reaccess and modify the code. I will post an example of use cases as soon as I get more time to.

Comment: Did you know that every batch "compiler" does NOT compile anything? They just create a sort of archive, which extracts the original batch script into a temporary folder (yes, in clear text) to execute it. This effectively loops you back to @Gerhard's "Then on the copyright..." comment. If you want to protect your intellectual work, use a language that actually compiles.

Comment: @Stephan so even if I use a batch to exe converter and compile that into an executable file which makes it an application, which does work, I've tested it already; you would be willing to go through the effort of decompiling the executable and attempt to reconstruct the source code so you could modify it and then recompile it? Does that sound like something someone would want to take the time to do. My goal is not for monitary value in the sense of marketing a DOS based txt rpg, because that's unrealistic.

Comment: The game will be completely free to download and play, although I would happily except donations to improve and or expand upon it, my end goal, is to one day produce a more legitimate game with the intellectual work that is the broader aspect of what this little side project of mine currently is becoming. On a side note, I've already decided to just set a base value for each equation, sure it takes more time but I don't mind it. If anyone cares to tell me how to mark my problem as solved, let me know. I have only used this website for like 3 days now, kinda new here.

Comment: No need to decompile an application, because the application just unzips the original batch script into a temporary folder to execute it (and where anyone can read it) (just saying...). You close a question by accepting the answer (click the grey checkmark) that solved your problem or helped you most. If no answer is satisfying, you are encouraged to add an answer yourself and accept that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To perform a comparison of an expression in batch, you can use `Set /A` with an expression designed to evaluate as 0 if false in conjunction with `&&` or `||` conditional operators to implement if else logic.

IE:

```
@Echo off
:l
Set /A A=5,B=2
Set /P "C=Value for C: "

2> nul Set /A "D=B+C","1/(A-D)" && (
 Cmd /V:On /C "Echo(!A! ^!= !D!"
) || (
 Cmd /V:On /C "Echo(!A! == !D!"
)
Goto:l
```